# i want to skip record from mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to skip records what i am fetching from my MySQL query.
suppose my query is : select * from number;
output : 1 , 2  , 3 , 4 , 5.
so i want to skip record 2.
so how can i do this.
please explain step by step because i am beginner in php and mysql.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
order by id desc
```

`desc` stands for descending order
`asc` for ascending

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ORDER BY id DESC` in your query, more in detail [explained here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).

This way you reverse the order of results. And please do it this way and not via php or whatever language you are using afterwards ;).

Answer (score 0):

you should use `ORDER BY someattribute DESC` to obtain a descending order.

Answer (score 0):

You should amend `ORDER BY <primary_key_column_name> DESC` to your SQL query.
Can you type down the PHP script and the SQL query?